# DatePicker react-datepicker doesn't read dates in NVDA , announce blank

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, screen-readers, react-datepicker, nvda

DatePicker react-datepicker NVDA read each date as 'blank'. Does someone have a valid solution for this and managed to get the NVDA screen reader to say the date?[image] can be experienced in [reactdatepicker.com](https://reactdatepicker.com/) ,discussed in [github.com](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/1311)  and [relevant sandbox (not mine)](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7wx24xz44) when opened in whole window [datepicker announce blank](https://q7wx24xz44.csb.app/). NVDA can be run or downloaded from here https://www.nvaccess.org/download/

Comment: Much much more info is needed to help, code example will help

Comment: You can provide a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-sunset-10f8c) for your doubt, so others can edit that & help you

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm hitting this same issue. @skarlinski
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77965062/screen-reader-doesnt-read-cell-value-when-moving-accros-the-datepicker-grid