# Screen reader doesn't read cell value when moving accros the datepicker grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, screen-readers

I have the following datepicker. The problem is that when running screen reader (NVDA), when moving the selection on the datepicker grid to different cells using *keyboard*, the screen reader just says "blank". (However, if I hover over the cells with mouse, it does read the number of the day correctly.)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass("month-calendar-widget");
    $(".month-calendar input").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShow: function () {
          $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass("month-calendar-widget");
        }
    }).datepicker("setDate", convertDateToUTC(new Date()));
});
```

What I was hoping was to fix this issue by adding `aria-label` attribute to each cell of the grid using `beforeShowDay` like below:

```
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM d, yy', date);
    return [true, '', dateString + "" + 'aria-label="' + dateString + '" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false"'];
  }
```

However, this results in the follwing html which is wrong:

```
<td class=" " data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay" data-month="1" data-year="2024" title="February 16, 2024aria-label=&quot;February 16, 2024&quot; role=&quot;gridcell&quot; aria-selected=&quot;false&quot;">
    <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">16</a>
</td>
```

What am I missing?

**Update 1:**

To further clarify, here is my goal:

- Run NVDA (just google `nvda download` and download and run it)
- Navigate to, for example, the datepicker Diego provided in his answer below, then using *keyboard* move to different cells in the grid:
  [image]
- I am expecting NVDA say the date, but it just says "blank".

**update 2**

Use this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7e2xw45/1/) to play with Diego's answer

**update 3**

After further investigation, I *think* there is a fundamental issue with regard to accessibility of this JQuery datepicker: basically, imagine you cannot visually see the page and you tab into that field. Now there are two *simultaneous* options to enter the date: both by typing and moving across the datepicker grid. This is also probably why the screen-reader is confused too. I think the two options should have separate triggers: i.e. we have a text box where user can enter text, AND a button that is when clicked, opens the date picker where the user can now select a date. I looked some other implementations of the date-picker and they all seem to have implemented it this way. I also found this github issue for the same: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/issues/2155

Comment: I'm not still giving a solution but just hinting that [beforeShowDay](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) expects its 3rd arg to be _an optional popup tooltip for this date_ (that will be rendered as the value of the `title` attribute). It's not custom html to be appended inside the html element

Comment: You could _try_ using `dateString + '" ' + "aria-label='...` so that it ends the title attribute and starts a new one, and it will likely escape the quote marks, so you'd probably need to use single quotes (`'`) around the aria attribute values, but you're playing with fire...

Answer (score 1):

Since [beforeShowDay](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) supports only creating the value of the `title` attribute, and since the trick of closing the quote to add your further attribute may not be enough because it's addressing a td and not the interactive element, you may just use a different strategy to populate the `aria-label` attribute on the actual anchor.

You can rely on the option `beforeShow` that will run the function given just one moment before the datepicker is actually shown:

https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow

> beforeShow
> Type: Function( Element input, Object inst )
>
> A function that takes an input field and current datepicker instance
> and returns an options object to update the datepicker with. It is
> called just before the datepicker is displayed.

Such function will iterate over each interactive element inside the calendar containing every single day the user can pick (anchor element) and will add an `aria-label` attribute to it with the value coming from the `title` attribute on its parent cell (set by `beforeShowDay` as you did).

This is an example of a day cell being processed:

```
<td
  class="ui-datepicker-days-cell-over ui-datepicker-current-day ui-datepicker-today"
  title="February 9, 2024"
  data-handler="selectDay"
  data-event="click"
  data-month="1"
  data-year="2024">
    <a
      class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-active" href="#"
      aria-label="February 9, 2024">9</a>
</td>
```

There was the option of crafting the date by picking its parts from each component like this, but it was overkill:

```
const year = parentCell.attr('data-year');
const month = parentCell.attr('data-month');
const day = $(this).text();

const paddedMonth =
  (parseInt(month, 10) + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'); 
const paddedDay = day.padStart(2, '0'); 

//previously grab day info and format the correponding date
const formattedDate = `${paddedDay}/${paddedMonth}/${year}`;

//populate the day anchor with the aria-label containing dd/mm/yyyy
$(this).attr('aria-label', formattedDate);
```

As a further action I also dealt with the `onSelect` event that will add the `aria-label` attribute also to the input element once a date was selected inside the datepicker. It could be not needed since probably screen readers already can read the value of an input element.

**Edit**: as you found out with a library specifically designed to solve this particular problem, the datepicker doesn't move the focus while navigating over the calendar and it instead remains locked on the input field. That's why despite the 'aria-label` was set, it couldn't be read if the screenreader couldn't see the focus moving.

So the solution I provided here, so far, cannot fully address the scenario because it's missing the logics to deal with the focus.

That library I see instead is using a strategy based on the `tab-index` attribute and `aria-select` correctly achieving that goal.

I also used the option `showOn` as `button` so that the datepicker won't show up when the text input gained focus but only when the dedicated button is clicked.

https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn

> When the datepicker should appear. The datepicker can appear when the
> field receives focus ("focus"), when a button is clicked ("button"),
> or when either event occurs ("both").

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  /*
  $("#pickdate").click(function(){
    $(".month-calendar input").datepicker("show");
  });
  */

  $(".month-calendar input").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    minDate: 0,
    //prevent from showing on focus and use the default button instead
    //if you wish instead a custom button, uncomment both html and js related
    //and here use the option "none"
    showOn: "button",
    
    //on date selected
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      const value = "Selected date: " + dateText;
      //set the aria-label of the input element with the date picked
      $(this).attr("aria-label", value);
    },
    
    //before showing each day in the datepicker grid
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      //return a value used to populate the title attr of the day td
      const dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM d, yy', date);
      return [true, '', dateString];
    },
    
    //before showing the days grid
    beforeShow: function(input, inst){
      //set timeout is to wait for the ui to be rendered
      setTimeout(function() {
        //select the calendar element
        const daysGrid = $('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar');
        //fetch all the anchors being interactive days
        const interactiveDays = $(daysGrid).find('td a');
        
        //for each one of them
        interactiveDays.each(function(){
          const parentCell = $(this).closest('td');                                    
          //set the aria-label as the same value on the title attr of its parent
          $(this).attr('aria-label', $(parentCell).attr('title'));
          
          //...other aria attributes could be set at this point...
        });
      }); 
    }

  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

```css
button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="month-calendar">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
  <!--
  <button id="pickdate">datepicker</button>
  -->
</div>
```

Comment: A good strategy, although it would need to be tested to see if the attribute is set before the screen reader reads the element's attributes.

Comment: @diego-d are you sure this adds the attribute? I am looking at the td-elements on this page for that datepicker and I don't see the attributes being added. also screen reader still doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes I agree but all I could do was following the line _I was hoping was to fix this issue by adding aria-label attribute_. And I still believe it's a good lead since _the [aria-label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label) attribute can be used to define a string that labels the interactive element on which it is set._

Comment: @havij my code is actually adding the aria attribute to the input element originating the datepicker (`$(".month-calendar input")datepicker(...)`) . I could guess a `td` was involved watching at the html you shared where the title attribute was being set by `beforeShowDay` but it didn't make sense because your datepicker was bound as well as mine on the input element and how could that callback address any td anyhow? maybe if you update the question with more details about how is your html containing the input element and how it's related to any td, I can understand better

Comment: but yet you should understand that as I desribed earlier in my previous comment, the `aria-label` is expected to be added to interactive elements (such input) and not a td. So the scenario you described is still unclear. Plus what do you mean that the screen reader doesn't read it? did you focus on the input element? that's what's holding the value and that you wish to read.

Comment: @diego-d can you please run NVDA, then navigate to the datepicker you provided above, then navigate with _keyboard_ to different cells of the grid (using ctrl+arrows), then see what the screen reader reads?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking. I don't have a screen reader and I don't have NVDA installed. As far as I understand it's a software that reads the output of a web browser (or other application) and support a variety of devices that will interact with the user. The problem is that I can't verify the scenario in first person and I still don't understand what you mean by saying `then navigate with keyboard to different cells of the grid`. I have no grid. I just have an input text field with a datepicker associated. That's why I asked to be more clear but you didn't yet

Comment: ohhh maybe I get it now! you meant the grid of days in the datepicker itself! then my solution is totally out of topic!

Comment: @DiegoD yes that's what I meant, thanks for your comments and your response, you already clarified a few things for me! I added an update to further clarify my question.

Comment: @havij updated the answer with something closer to your question

Comment: @DiegoD this does seem to add the aria-label as I wanted thanks! but screenreader still says blank when moving to different cells using keyboard. one observation, when I navigate to the datepicker using keyborad (tab), then the aria-label is _not_ added to the `a` elements. could this be the issue?

Comment: I observed something interesting, I think the reason why NVDA doesn't recognize the cells is because the "focus" stays in the text box even when we move across the datepicker grid cells. NVDA works as expected on this example: https://jsfiddle.net/j49gz3g3

Comment: I think there is a fundamental issue with regard to accessibility of this JQuery datepicker: basically Imagine you cannot visually see the page and you tab into that field. Now there are two _simultaneous_ options to enter the date: both by typing and moving across the datepicker grid. This is also probably why the screen-reader is confused too. I think the two options should have separate triggers: i.e. we have a text box where user can enter text, AND a button that is when clicked, opens the date picker where the user can now select a date.

Comment: I edited my answer and included the feature for the datepicker to show up on demand only when the dedicated button is clicked instead of when the text input gained focus